# rsync changing already existing files

Tags: backup, cron, rsync

I have a simple line of rsync in my crontab that gets backup files from the prod server to another.

It looks like it is touching the already existing files in the destination folder. This way, the backup would incrementally take longer each interval.

Please take a look at the date and time the files below have changed.

How do I use rsync not to touch (and download?) the files it already has. I don't need any checksums calculated either, once the backups are created, they won't change anymore.

```
rsync -vzre 'ssh' stor@server:/backup/system/ /storage/share/Backup/Server
```

The files to be fetched:

```
-rw-r-x--- 1 root stor 896K Jun 22 05:02 giant-140622-etc.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 root stor 620K Jun 22 05:02 giant-140622-sql.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 root stor  84M Jun 22 05:02 giant-140622-www.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 root stor 899K Jun 25 05:00 giant-140625-etc.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 root stor 603K Jun 25 05:00 giant-140625-sql.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 root stor  84M Jun 25 05:00 giant-140625-www.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 root stor 899K Jun 28 05:00 giant-140628-etc.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 root stor 620K Jun 28 05:00 giant-140628-sql.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 root stor  86M Jun 28 05:00 giant-140628-www.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 root stor 899K Jun 30 05:00 giant-140630-etc.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 root stor 617K Jun 30 05:00 giant-140630-sql.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 root stor  86M Jun 30 05:00 giant-140630-www.zip
```

The destination:

```
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 896K Jun 30 06:06 giant-140622-etc.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 620K Jun 30 06:06 giant-140622-sql.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor  84M Jun 30 06:06 giant-140622-www.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 899K Jun 30 06:06 giant-140625-etc.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 603K Jun 30 06:06 giant-140625-sql.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor  84M Jun 30 06:06 giant-140625-www.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 899K Jun 30 06:06 giant-140628-etc.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 620K Jun 30 06:06 giant-140628-sql.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor  86M Jun 30 06:06 giant-140628-www.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 899K Jun 30 06:07 giant-140630-etc.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 617K Jun 30 06:08 giant-140630-sql.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor  86M Jun 30 06:10 giant-140630-www.zip
```

**Update:**

When I run the `rsync` command (with the `--skip-existing` arg) from the shell, it only downloads non-existing new files and skips the files it already has.

When investigating **the behaviour of the exact same command run by a cronjob**, the already existing files **do change every cycle** and the whole **job takes incrementally longer each cycle** (**compare the times above, cronjob starting at 06:00, 2 minutes per file even if they already exist**).

```
rsync -vzr --ignore-existing -e 'ssh -i /path/id_rsa -l backup' backup@flowl.info:/backup/system/ /nfs/share-private/Backup/Server
```

**Update:**

Here are the files form july, I put an extra blank line into, please see the times, which started by `06:01` and raise each new files.

```
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 899K Jul  4 06:01 giant-140702-etc.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 621K Jul  4 06:01 giant-140702-sql.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor  86M Jul  4 06:03 giant-140702-www.zip
                                       ^-- 01 to 03
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 899K Jul  4 06:04 giant-140704-etc.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 634K Jul  4 06:05 giant-140704-sql.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor  86M Jul  8 06:02 giant-140704-www.zip
                                       ^-- ???
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 899K Jul  8 06:03 giant-140706-etc.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 629K Jul  8 06:03 giant-140706-sql.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor  86M Jul  8 06:06 giant-140706-www.zip
                                       ^-- 03 - 06
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 899K Jul  8 06:07 giant-140708-etc.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 629K Jul  8 06:07 giant-140708-sql.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor  86M Jul  8 06:10 giant-140708-www.zip
                                       ^-- 07 - 10
```

Now when I imagine going on another month, the time would be like:

```
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 899K Jul  8 06:32 giant-140808-etc.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor 629K Jul  8 06:32 giant-140808-sql.zip
-rw-r-x--- 1 stor stor  86M Jul  8 06:35 giant-140808-www.zip
                                       ^-- what I imagine to happen
```

Comment: I suggest you try running `fuser` to see if any process currently has the files open. If any process is keeping the files open for writing, it should show up. Additionally, I suggest that before the next time you run rsync, compute a checksum on all files on both source and destination, such that you know which files differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the `--ignore-existing` command and it looks like it won't change anything and only download new files.

```
rsync -vzr --ignore-existing -e
```

**Edit:** When there are new files it still takes longer each cycle.

Answer (score 4):

By default `rsync` will read the entire file on both source and destination, to verify that they are identical. This does not consume network bandwidth, as it will only be comparing a hash value. But it does spend time reading from the disk.

In one usage scenario, I found this to be terribly inefficient because the source files were only being appended to. I used the `--size-only`, which worked well for me.

There is a few other options, which look like they may be applicable, `--append` and `--append-verify`, but I haven't tested those myself.

It does not look like you have a directory with a lot of small files, so the time to read the directory listing from disk and stat each file, shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: I put in `--size-only`, in combination with `--ignore-existing`. I also updated my question to make it more clear what I imagine to happen.

Comment: OH my.... look at the day downloaded: `Jul  8`... it makes so much sense now.

Answer (score 2):

I think adding `-t` to your argument list will help.

To verify this you could add `--itemize-changes` to the arguments (without `-t`). If I understood you correctly, this would show the `T`-flag in every line

`man 1 rspec`:

> A  t  means  the modification time is different and is being updated
>   to the sender’s value (requires --times).  An alternate value of T
>   means that the modification time will be set to the transfer time,
>   which happens when a file/symlink/device is updated without --times
>   and when a symlink is changed and the receiver can’t set its time. 
>   (Note: when  using  an  rsync  3.0.0 client, you might see the s flag
>   combined with t instead of the proper T flag for this time-setting
>   failure.)

After this add `-t` to the command (keep `--itemize-changes`) and you will receive a `t`-flag on every line. In the next run the list will only contain the new files.

This is my example run:

```
krissi@host ~/tmp/rsync % l *
dst:
total 0

src:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 krissi users 0 Jul 13 18:05 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 krissi users 0 Jul 13 18:05 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 krissi users 0 Jul 13 18:19 later
krissi@host ~/tmp/rsync % rsync -vzr --itemize-changes src/ dst/
sending incremental file list
>f+++++++++ bar
>f+++++++++ foo
>f+++++++++ later

sent 174 bytes  received 69 bytes  486.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
krissi@host ~/tmp/rsync % l *
dst:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 krissi users 0 Jul 13 18:21 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 krissi users 0 Jul 13 18:21 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 krissi users 0 Jul 13 18:21 later

src:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 krissi users 0 Jul 13 18:05 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 krissi users 0 Jul 13 18:05 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 krissi users 0 Jul 13 18:19 later
krissi@host ~/tmp/rsync % rsync -vzr --itemize-changes src/ dst/
sending incremental file list
>f..T...... bar
>f..T...... foo
>f..T...... later

sent 174 bytes  received 69 bytes  486.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
krissi@host ~/tmp/rsync % rsync -vzr --itemize-changes src/ dst/
sending incremental file list
>f..T...... bar
>f..T...... foo
>f..T...... later

sent 174 bytes  received 69 bytes  486.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
krissi@host ~/tmp/rsync % rsync -vzrt --itemize-changes src/ dst/
sending incremental file list
.d..t...... ./
>f..t...... bar
>f..t...... foo
>f..t...... later

sent 177 bytes  received 72 bytes  498.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
krissi@host ~/tmp/rsync % rsync -vzrt --itemize-changes src/ dst/
sending incremental file list

sent 66 bytes  received 12 bytes  156.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
krissi@host ~/tmp/rsync % l *
dst:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 krissi users 0 Jul 13 18:05 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 krissi users 0 Jul 13 18:05 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 krissi users 0 Jul 13 18:19 later

src:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 krissi users 0 Jul 13 18:05 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 krissi users 0 Jul 13 18:05 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 krissi users 0 Jul 13 18:19 later
```

Answer (score 1):

why do you say it takes longer each time? how is that possible?

maybe it's the program generating the files that is touching them?

try with `--checksum`: skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size, see if that changes anything (i wouldn't keep this option because it reads every file from the disk every time, too expensive, i'm only suggesting it to find the problem.)

(and maybe try to debug with the `-t` option, that preserves modification times)

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear what I mean with it taking longer each cycle.

Comment: i think you should try to see the difference between using `--checksum`, `--size-only` and `--update`