# Combining rsync -t and --ignore-existing

Tags: rsync, file-transfer

I'd like to preserve the time of modification for files that did not exist on target, but do not change files that already exist, even if the modification times differ. I thought that rsync with `-t` and `--ignore-existing` would be a perfect fit for that (reference below).

> --times, -t preserve modification times
>
> --ignore-existing skip updating files that exist on receiver

Just to be on the safe side, I compared the output of two commands:

`rsync -rlv --dry-run dir1 dir2` and `rsync -rlv --ignore-existing --dry-run dir1 dir2` print the same 3 files, which indeed do not exist on the target.

However, `rsync -rlvt --dry-run dir1 dir2` and `rsync -rlvt --ignore-existing --dry-run dir1 dir2` print a few hundred files. Most of them, with the exception of the mentioned 3, exist in dir2. It seems that `--ignore-existing` takes no effect when combined with `-t`: the number of lines returned is the same in both cases.

Per [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/608955/rsync-changing-already-existing-files) I also tried `--size-only`, but it didn't help either.

Why is that? What should I do to achieve my intended behaviour?

Comment: [Relevant bug report in Debian BTS](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1060235)